# Certificates in WCF mutual certificates authentication

Tags: .net, wcf, certificate, x509

Should the X.509 certificates used in WCF client and WCF service be signed by certificate authority (VeriSign)? Or they can be signed by Windows Root authority?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They can even be self-signed if the corresponding public keys are available to the parties.